# How do I use Asp.Net Image control in jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, image, controls

I would like to know how to use a normal Asp.Net Image control in jquery to display it's URL path as `Image1.Imageurl=""`

This is my script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        // Convert divs to queue widgets when the DOM is ready
        $(function () {
            $("#uploader").plupload({
                // General settings
                runtimes: 'gears,flash,silverlight,browserplus,html5',
                url: 'Final.aspx',
                max_file_size: '10mb',
                max_file_count: 25,
                chunk_size: '1mb',
                unique_names: true,

                // Resize images on clientside if we can
                //                    resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90 },

                // Specify what files to browse for
                filters: [
            { title: "Image files", extensions: "jpg,gif,png" },
            { title: "Zip files", extensions: "zip" }
        ],

//                resize: { width: 320, height: 240, quality: 90, beforeUpload: false },

                // thumbnails
                thumb: { width: 100, height: 100, quality: 90 },

                // Flash settings
                flash_swf_url: 'js/plupload.flash.swf',

                // Silverlight settings
                silverlight_xap_url: 'js/plupload.silverlight.xap'
            });


            // Client side form validation
            $('form').submit(function (e) {
                var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');

                // Files in queue upload them first
                if (uploader.files.length > 0) {
                    // When all files are uploaded submit form
                    uploader.bind('StateChanged', function () {
                        if (uploader.files.length === (uploader.total.uploaded + uploader.total.failed)) {
                            $('form')[0].submit();
                        }
                    });

                    uploader.start();
                }
                else
                    alert('You must at least upload one file.');

                return false;
            });
            var uploader = $('#uploader').plupload('getUploader');
            uploader.bind('FileUploaded', function (up, file, res) {

                $('#showfilelist').append("<div id=" + file.id + " class='thumb'><a href='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' target='_blank' rel='gallery'><img src='uploads/" + document.getElementById("currentDirectory").value + "/" + file.name + "' width='50' height='50'/></a></div>");

            });    
        });
</script>
```

When the upload is done I need to display only one image inside the image control as If use append then it is adding all the images.

Here is my Image control:

```
 <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" BackColor="#0099CC" BorderStyle="None" 
                                Height="624px" Width="500px" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`Image.ImageUrl` translates to `<img src=''>` so set the `src` attribute with JQuery.  You would just have to have a technique to derive the URL you need for the client, to display that particular image.

Comment: Actually in the code above I have a div named showfilelist and displaying all the uploaded images now If I use <img src=''> and then how do I add this image to the desired Image.ImageURL and If I use append then all the images are appending to it.

Comment: You can't use append - because you have a list of images, and only want to show one.  So I have to ask a question; if you want to show only one image, when multiple images are uploaded, which one do you want to show (first, last, a slideshow)?

Comment: I would like to upload the first Image or the last one and no such preferences.